# ngblur and enter event : why on enter key two http calls go?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onblur

I have a form in which I have `enter-key` press event and `ng-blur`. It's like when a user enters something and click elsewhere the form is submitted similarly if a user writes something and press enter the form is submitted and API call goes.

**Problem Statement**

It works fine on `ng-blur` only a single call goes to the API. But when I try to use key event two calls go. That's why two success messages show. I don't know why but it acting like that.

**Form**

```
input ng-model="cusBoard.boardData.musicalWorkName"
      id="superTitleInput" class="title-edit-input superTitle-input" type="text"
      maxlength="50"
      my-key-enter="cusBoard.updateInfo()"
      ng-blur="cusBoard.updateInfo()">
```

**My-key-enter Directive**

```
app.directive('myKeyEnter', function () {
return {
    controller: 'SignInController',
    link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
        elements.bind('keydown keypress', function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.myKeyEnter);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**controller function**

```
function updateInfo(){
    editable('superTitle',0);
    var params = {
        superTitle : cusBoard.boardData.musicalWorkName,
        boardId : cusBoard.boardData._id
    };
    CastingBoard.updateSuperTitle(params).then(function (res) {
        if (res.msgCode === '405') {
            $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().textContent("Board title updated successfully.").position('bottom right'));
        }
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding to both the `keydown` and `keypress` events:

```
        elements.bind('keydown keypress', function (event) {
```

Both events are fired for the Enter key, so the handler is executed twice.

Just pick one, or the other.